# Angular horizontal bar chart.js

Tags: angular, chart.js

I want to create horizontal bar dataset:[] giving only postive values and i need to place y-axis line between what I want is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IJ2I.jpg) the image but I'm getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diFIO.jpg) way which is not according to my requirement.

```
New chart(ctx,{
type:'bar';
data:{
 datasets:[{   
     Labels: [-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5]
     data:[20,40,100,80]
     Backgroundcolor: blue;
     }],

    Options:{
      responsive:true,
      indexAxis:'y',
      Scales:{
         Position:top
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    scales: {
      y: {
        position: 'top',
      },
    },
  },
};

const data = {
  labels: [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My Dataset',
    data: [20, 40, 100, 80],
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  }],
};
```